# Basic SQL OrderBy query

Tags: sql

The query below works fine and returns correct result as I need

```
select top 1 SID from vSTable where (ID in 
(select ID from Engine where Name='nnn' OR Name='mmm') 
and QuestionTypeID=1 and IsOfficial=1) order by vSTable.ITime desc;
```

but when I use it like this

```
declare @SVal as int

set @SVal = select top 1 SID 
            from vSTable 
            where (
              ID in 
                  (select ID from Engine where Name='nnn' OR Name='mmm') 
              and QuestionTypeID=1 
              and IsOfficial=1
            ) order by vSTable.ITime desc;
```

I get the error incorrect syntax near select stmt

Comment: are you using a stored procedure?

Comment: which DBMS are you using? SQL Server/MySQL etc.,

Answer (score 1):

wrap the select statement in parenthesis

```
declare @SVal as int

set @SVal = (select top 1 SID 
            from vSTable 
            where (
              ID in 
                  (select ID from Engine where Name='nnn' OR Name='mmm') 
              and QuestionTypeID=1 
              and IsOfficial=1
            ) order by vSTable.ITime desc);
```

Comment: Awesome thanks works now!

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is a little off.  This should work:

```
  select @SVal = (select top 1 SID from vSTable where (ID in 
  (select ID from Engine where Name='nnn' OR Name='mmm') 
  and QuestionTypeID=1 and IsOfficial=1) order by vSTable.ITime desc)
```

Note that you can use either SET or SELECT for that assignment.

Comment: Awesome thanks works now!